# What is the text element in the context of the System.Globalization.StringInfo in C#?

Tags: c#, string, text, character

What is the text element in the context of the `System.Globalization.StringInfo` in C#?

I come over the concept of the text elements while learning the C# through the **CLR via C#**. And it seems that the book reader should clearly understand what the text element is all about. But I am not getting that concept at all.

Also, [the](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.stringinfo.getnexttextelement?view=netframework-4.8) documentation is not very verbose on the topic.

I would like to find out the definition of what the text element is.

My guess is that it is just a Unicode character, which is not necessary represented by a single `System.Char` (because in some cases it can be represented by two `System.Char`: high and low surrogates). But I am not sure that my guess is correct.

My other guess is that it is a whole word.

The text elements are mentioned in this piece of code in the **CLR via C#** book:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public sealed class Program {
 public static void Main() {
  // The string below contains combining characters
  String s = "a\u0304\u0308bc\u0327";
  SubstringByTextElements(s);
  EnumTextElements(s);
  EnumTextElementIndexes(s);
 }
 private static void SubstringByTextElements(String s) {
  String output = String.Empty;
  StringInfo si = new StringInfo(s);
  for (Int32 element = 0; element < si.LengthInTextElements; element++) {
   output += String.Format(
    "Text element {0} is '{1}'{2}",
    element, si.SubstringByTextElements(element, 1),
    Environment.NewLine);
  }
  MessageBox.Show(output, "Result of SubstringByTextElements");
 }
 private static void EnumTextElements(String s) {
  String output = String.Empty;
  TextElementEnumerator charEnum =
   StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s);
  while (charEnum.MoveNext()) {
   output += String.Format(
    "Character at index {0} is '{1}'{2}",
    charEnum.ElementIndex, charEnum.GetTextElement(),
    Environment.NewLine);
  }
  MessageBox.Show(output, "Result of GetTextElementEnumerator");
 }
 private static void EnumTextElementIndexes(String s) {
  String output = String.Empty;
  Int32[] textElemIndex = StringInfo.ParseCombiningCharacters(s);
  for (Int32 i = 0; i < textElemIndex.Length; i++) {
   output += String.Format(
    "Character {0} starts at index {1}{2}",
    i, textElemIndex[i], Environment.NewLine);
  }
  MessageBox.Show(output, "Result of ParseCombiningCharacters");
 }
}
```

Comment: Under **Remarks**, it says, *".NET defines a text element as a unit of text that is displayed as a single character, that is, a grapheme. A text element can be a base character, a surrogate pair, or a combining character sequence."*

Comment: Related reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @madreflection, thank you for the note about the **System.Globalization.StringInfo**. Could you, please, add your last comment as an answer? Also, would you be so kind to provide the definition for the **combining character sequence** as well?

Comment: Incidentally, the remarks also confirm your guess about surrogate pairs.

Comment: @madreflection, maybe you know what is the difference between a character and a text element? Because, the chapter in the **CLR via C#** book is called **Examining a String’s Characters and Text Elements**, implying that a character and a text element are not the same things.

Comment: @madreflection, from the definition I see that the text elements are displayed as characters. Does it mean that we can call the text element in other words as an internal characters representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under **Remarks**, the documentation you linked says:

> .NET defines a text element as a unit of text that is displayed as a single character, that is, a grapheme. A text element can be a base character, a surrogate pair, or a combining character sequence.

I'm no expert but an example of a combining character sequence would be a letter followed by a combining diacritic, such as `a` combined with `´` (combining acute accent) creates `á`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477420) is  a good example of those "combining characters" (in addition to being good educational resource :) )